# Make a boolean false after every n number of minutes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, django

I have a table with a boolean value, if that value is not explicitly set to anything in the database for a few minutes by the back-end (django) then it must automatically be set to false. How do I do that in MySQL efficiently?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what do you mean by 'if the value is not set to anything for a few minutes'? What flavour and version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I have modified the question, and there is no constraint on flavor and version of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the MySQL event scheduler to run a a query to update all rows where the age of the row is greater than your threshold and have it execute the update at a suitable interval.